# Analysis Design Help

Tags: anova

I'm having trouble determining the statistical analysis that should be used in order to analyze the data set accompanying this problem.

I have narrowed the choices (in my textbook) down to either a completely randomized factorial design or a randomized block design. Both seem very similar, and based on the information the question presents either could be used. I would like a second opinion on that assumption, however. We work out of Kirk's 2012 Experimental Design textbook if that helps at all. Any advice or information is greatly appreciated!

The problem:

"Dr. B is working with the Air Force to develop a display for remotely piloted aircraft (RPA) pilots. The Air Force had three types of tasks that they want RPA pilots to be able to complete: surveillance, patrol, and exploration. Dr. B. studied three display types for these tasks: ecological, configural and the standard display. Twenty-two RPA pilots from the Air Force were scored doing each type of task on each display type. Thus, the pilots did each task on each display. The order in which the pilots were exposed to the treatments was counterbalanced. Dr. B has come to you to analyze her data."

From what the problem states, there are three independent variables, each with 3 conditions. (3x3 Anova) Each treatment uses the same 22 participants making it a repeated measures design.

Comment: If this is a exercise from a course, then please include the self-study tag.

Comment: Please do not vandalize your question. When you posted on SE, you gave up 
ownership of the content under
[CC BY-SA 4.0](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/licensing). If there are 
no answers, you may delete your own question (see 
[here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question)
): just click the faint gray 'delete' at lower left (your account needs to be 
registered for this). Otherwise, the thread will remain according to SE's rules.